# Possible to give "Network Service" on one computer permission to a directory on another computer?

Tags: windows-services, file-permissions

I have a file:

```
\\Computer1\Share\file.pdf
```

and I need to open in using a service running as the network service account on another computer:

```
Computer2\NETWORK SERVICE
```

FWIW, Both `Computer1` and `Computer2` are on the same domain `Domain1`

**Is it possible to accomplish this task?**

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this programmatically, or just using explorer? Using explorer, you can add computers into the "Add User" dialogs under security/sharing, via the "Object Types" button.

Comment: How would I add the user though? `\Computer2\NETWORK SERVICE` is not found since the share is on `Computer1` and obviously nothing like `Domain1\Computer2\NETWORK SERVICE` works either...

Comment: When a service running under `NETWORK SERVICE` connects to another machine, it appears as *the computer* - so you'd grant appropriate permissions to `COMPUTER2`. But this *isn't* a programming question.

Comment: I kind of was figuring that it wasn't going to be possible and that a programming solution would be needed.  If not though, this is even better...  The issue I see with granting `NETWORK SERVICE` permission to the folder is that then couldn't any user on the network create and run a service to have access to the directory? (Right now the service is the only thing with access...It then looks at the Windows user name and determines what files the user should have access to).  Thanks!!!

Comment: No, as I say, you grant permissions to the *computer* - so "any user" would have to be able to run something as NETWORK SERVICE on COMPUTER2 for it to be granted the same permissions as your service, which presumably they cannot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes.**

If both servers are on the same domain then you can enable access to the share for `Domain1\Computer2$` (where `Computer2$` represents Network Service on Computer2).

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: @WalterStabosz The "NETWORK SERVICE" account is "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service".  It is the same account domain-wide and actually independent of the domain because it is part of NT AUTHORITY.  All that is required is to edit the Access Control List and add that account and the results will speak for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd use a domain account to run the service and grant that same domain account the appropriate permissions on the remote computer.

I don't like to claim this is the answer as whilst it would resolve the problem it doesn't address the question as asked - but it is the "right" solution, assuming that its possible to elect to run the service using something other the Network Service account...

Comment: But the only reason that Network Service exists (compared to Local Service) is that it allows services running under that account to access remote resources...

Comment: Damien, I plead ignorance and delight that there is (notionally) a better solution. Will a) do homework and then b) edit...