# SQL Server: xp_fileexist and UNC path permissions

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm attempting to run an ad hoc query in SQL Server Management Studio that uses the undocumented stored procedure `xp_fileexist`. I want to test for the existence of files in a subfolder under a network shared folder accessed via a UNC path.

Here's a [sqlservercentral post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic533876-146-2.aspx#bm1057641) that talks about the execution context of `xp_fileexist`.  From what I can tell I've got all the necessary permissions in place:

- I'm running SQL Server Management Studio from a domain account that has Full Control of the shared folder and its subfolders.
- The SQL account is linked to the domain account and has the `sysadmin` role.
- The SQL Server service logs on as `Network Service`.
- `Network Service` has Full Control of the shared folder and its subfolders.

I'm concerned that some of these permission settings might be overkill, yet `xp_fileexist` still cannot see the subfolder contents.

```sql
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist '\\servername\sharename\subfolder\filename.txt'
```

```
File Exists |File is a Directory |Parent Directory Exists
---------------------------------------------------------
0           |0                   |0
```

But `xp_fileexist` does see the shared folder itself.

```sql
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist '\\servername\sharename'
```

```
File Exists |File is a Directory |Parent Directory Exists
---------------------------------------------------------
0           |1                   |1
```

**Questions**:

Why are the shared folder's contents invisible?

And what security settings are actually necessary?

Comment: Stop using xp_filexist and use CLR.

Comment: yes, yes.  I was hoping I could be forgiven for trying to use `xp_fileexist` in an ad hoc query to solve a short term problem.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432556/possible-to-give-network-service-on-one-computer-permission-to-a-directory-on

Comment: Thank you, Tony.  Problem solved!  That was the piece of the puzzle I had not previously understood.