# ssrs master.dbo.xp_fileexist get different result based on user account

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

SSRS dataset uses a query with a udf "fc_FileExists" to check user's photo existence. if the photo doesn't exist, will use anonymous photo. (the anonymous photo is at the same folder with other photos). This ssrs report is running in intranet domain environment. When I run this report, I can see photo. but some other users can't. They just see the anonymous photo. The code is like below.

```
CASE WHEN dbo.fc_FileExists('\\domain\folder\'+ID+'.jpg') = 1 
    THEN 'file:\\domain\folder\'+ID+'.jpg'
     WHEN dbo.fc_FileExists('\\domain\folder\'+ID+'.jpg') = 0 
    THEN 'file:\\domain\folder\anonymous .jpg'
```

Problem is for some user, they always get anonymous photos. That means the photo could exist there but dbo.fc_FileExists always return 0. But why I can see the photo.

Any help please

AND The source code for fc_FileExists is as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fc_FileExists](@path varchar(8000)) 
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @result INT
     EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result OUTPUT
     RETURN cast(@result as bit)
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's one of two things:

1. Permissions: some users do not have permission to view the folder.
2. The ID does not exist in the table.

If at all possible, connect to SQL Query Analyser as a user that shows the anonymous photo and then  run the function - any errors? If not, **as the same user** try using windows explorer to find the users picture.

Comment: Thanks BIDeveloper. I did the test, the user can access that folder and the ID and file exists in that folder. but I run fc_FileExists('\\domain\folder\'+ID+'.jpg') on his machine is always get 0 no matter what. But in my machine, I can get correct results. I check Current_User, my is dbo, his is 'domain\user', any suggestion?

Comment: I'll lay money this is a windows permissions issue. Can you post fc_FileExists source?

Comment: I just post the fc_FileExists source.

Comment: This post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100845/sql-server-xp-fileexist-and-unc-path-permissions also references this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432556/possible-to-give-network-service-on-one-computer-permission-to-a-directory-on

Answer (score 0):

I figured that this is not good way. Actually ssrs can use System.IO.File.Exists directly. So we don't have to do this job at sql server side. I think the performance should be better.