# ssrs System.IO.File.Exists works well on local but not working on server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, system.io.file

I have a Sql reporting (ssrs). For the image, I use System.IO.File.Exists to check if the file (UNC path) exists or not. It works well on my local but after I upload to server, it always return false.

any suggestion?

Comment: How many more times can we tell you that this is a permissions issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487345/ssrs-master-dbo-xp-fileexist-get-different-result-based-on-user-account

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that we need change Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions on server side.

problem solved

see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8ab26a11-af38-44f1-9010-b4f8354a4e14/systemiofileexists-not-working?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: For further clarification, the setting in question can be found in the following file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS[version #].MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rssrvpolicy.config